# Fail SSIS Script Component from Vb.Net Class Library

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I'm struggling with following requirement, can someone please help:

Got SSIS Package which calls a dotnet libary for database functions. How can we pass Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure from VB.NET to make that SSIS Script Component FAIL if there is any error in DOTNET Library.

Regards

Comment: I'm afraid that you will need to provide significantly more details than you already have in order for anyone to help you. Setting the DTS.TaskResult to ScriptResults.Failure *will* cause a script component to fail, so your question doesn't make sense as is. What .Net Library do you mean? What Database are you using ? What happens when the script component completes or fails? What result are you expecting that you are not currently getting. What have you already tried. Do you have any code samples?

Comment: I use this is vb.net code - Throw (New Exception()) and that runs fine if are running the ETL Package fail. But when run this ETL Package as SQL Job it doesn't do anything and stop at this exception statement

Comment: Well, yes it will `Throw()` will stop the execution of your Script Task. But when it completes you can trap it with a Failure Precedence Constraint. Avoid Throw() statements, they're rather abrupt and rude. Do a controlled exit and trap and log any errors instead.

Comment: If you want to see the information about the error message. You need to use "Dts.Events.FireError(0, "<<You component>>", "<<Error / Exception description you wanted to display>>", string.Empty, 0);" before calling DTS.TaskResult to failure. so that error message will be written into the SQL job events.